# Safari and IIS Windows Integrated Security

Tags: security, browser, safari

Is it possible to use Safari4 with an IIS hosted Intranet site that uses IntegratedSecurity (NTLM)? InternetExplorer and Firefox are capable of dealing with it. I couldn't find a way to get it working with Safari though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer. **No**

The webkit engine does not have a way to deal with NTLM as yet, and there are no plans as far as a I am aware for this.

SharePoint has built a workaround for this in the way they handle cookies in SP2 and in 2010 for example, to allow the server to 'think' that the browser is NTLM authenticated.

<sub>I have been investigating this for the last 6 months, we have 150+ Mac users that need access to SharePoint for example, and Safari is my personal favorite browser</sub>

Comment: thanks. But why does firefox have some kind of support for it?

Comment: Firefox is not based on WebKit, and it started having a bigger corporate appeal. Safari is not considered a corporate browser. That would be my guess, no one would know for certain why unless they wrote the code.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Safari (5.0.5) does have support for IIS using Windows Integrated Security.

Comment: Hi Brian. That sounds great. Have you any references? If safari supports it, I wonder whether Chrome would have it too.

Comment: No official references.  I just tested Safari on an internal site I am developing for my company and it works.  In Safari and Firefox users get prompted for their username/password and have to enter their username like '<domain>\<username>'.  The current version of Chrome works as well without prompting for a username/password.